# How does React or Next make their <a> tag not reload the page but content loads?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, next.js

So, I'm now studying *NextJS*, using *Link* from *'next/link'*, something I couldn't just figure out is eventually `<Link>` component renders an `<a>` tag, with `href='/tosomewhere/'` on it like this here:

[image: Click to see tag]]

and when clicked, it just reloads some content *WITHOUT REFRESHING PAGE.*
But the traditional `<a>` tag just refreshes the page..

How does React and Next manages to do that? I couldn't find any information about it, can you eloborate me what relies under the hood?

Comment: There’s browser API that can change this default behavior. If my memory serves me well, i think it’s `history.push` plus some kind of `event.preventDefault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how they wrote the code, but I do this when I need to:

```
<a
  href="/home"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    history.push('/home')
  }}
>
  Go to home
</a>
```

[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) would prevent the default behavior of the hyperlink.

I use this approach even when I have to create a dummy link ([no eslint warning](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md)):

```
function doThis() {
  // open a modal, do logout, make an API call or anything 
}

...

<a
  href="/"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    doThis()
  }}
>
  Do this
</a>
```